# Find matching key/value pairs in Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Suppose this is my hashmap:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("animal", "Golden Retriever");
map.put("size", "big");
map.put("color","light golden");
```

By the help of this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35334940/11124256) I figured out how to get one specific matching element key-value pair by passing the key-value testdata and the map itself to the function.

Now, I'd like to extend the functionality so that the app takes more than one key-value pairs as parameter and still figure out if there's any matching element.

I suppose that the way I could handle this task is to first change the parameters to the function so that it takes two hashmaps instead. In here there would be eventually a loop which runs the testdata over the original hashmap and see if there is any matching element or not.

What is the best way to deal with this task?

Comment: The solution that you proposed seems good, what is wrong with that?

Comment: Please bear with me. The solution itself works very good when it comes to 1 single key-value pair. What I want like to achieve is to implement a function that takes two hashmaps as parameters. My goal is here now to check whether there are some sort of match between the two hashmaps.

I've looked into ".equals" but it does not really solve my problem, as a hashmap of 2 key / value pairs (testdata) will never be equal to a hashmap of 3 key-value pairs (The original hashmap), and will therefore return false.

Comment: I understood what you wanted to achieve, but you also proposed an approach, by using two hashmaps. One that keeps the values, and the other that keeps the search key/values.

Comment: @Ph100 - you should look at the answers provided and accept one. Both seem to do the job.

Comment: Honestly, the real answer is: start trying. Programming is about making experience yourself. Just sit down and start thinking then coding. Don't start with asking others. Trust me, trying is better than asking. Sure, when you are stuck with your code for hours, then ask for help. But don't consider asking the first option!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass two HashMaps and loop through one and check if there is a match in the other one. 
Method takes in haystack as the one to check for any needles in it. Returns boolean accordingly

```
public boolean ifContains(HashMap<String, String> haystack, HashMap<String, String> needles) {
    for (String key : haystack.keySet()) {
        if (needles.containsKey(key) && needles.get(key).equals(haystack.get(key))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether your data map's entries contains one of your search map's entries using a stream:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("animal", "Golden Retriever");
        data.put("size", "big");
        data.put("color", "light golden");


        Map<String, String> search = new HashMap<>();
        search.put("size", "small");
        search.put("color", "light golden");

        boolean matches = search.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(it -> data.entrySet().contains(it));

        System.out.println(matches);
    }
}
```

This works by virtue of [`Map.Entry.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) being defined in terms of key and value equality.

Your utility method could look as follows:

```
public static <T, U> boolean matches(Map<T, U> data, Map<T, U> search) {
    return search.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .anyMatch(it -> data.entrySet().contains(it));
}
```